# Algumas dúvidas com o Sync Framework Microsoft

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Estou pensando em implantar o `Sync Framework` em uma solução que estou desenvolvendo, porém tenho tido algumas dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento do `Framework`, espero que vocês possam me ajudar, ficarei muito agradecido.

A primeira dúvida é:

Tenho um Banco de Dados local em .mdf e um banco de dados em um servidor externo com SQL server Express. Onde o banco de dados local trabalha junto ao programa de forma offline e o SQL server funciona como nuvem para arquivar todos dados do meu cliente.

O Sync Framework consegue fazer o trabalho de sincronizar as alterações do banco de dados local com o banco de dados externo? Ou seja, tudo que for adicionado ou removido no banco de dados local, ser também adicionado ou removido no banco de dados externo.

A segunda dúvida é:

O `sync framework` tem um bom desempenho? Por exemplo: em um caso que seja feita mais de 5 mil modificações no banco de dados ele demoraria muito para fazer a sincronização?

Atenciosamente.

Comment: Para sua segunda dúvida, seu problema com desempenho provavelmente será o Banco e não o framework. SQL Server Express não foi feito para ser executado em produção.

Comment: @gmsantos SQLExpress funciona muito bem em produção, ele foi feito, justamente, para cenários de menor concorrência. Suas limitações hoje são os 10GB de tamanho máximo e quantidade de CPUs disponíveis para o motor do banco de dados. Com cargas pequenas o banco roda muito rapidamente. O que não serve para produção é banco ACCESS, nem como banco de dados local da aplicação. Pode-se usar o SQLExpress localmente (ótima opção para o sync) ou o SQL Compact que oferece praticamente as mesmas capacidades e é muito mais simples de distribuir com a aplicação.

Comment: Felipe, eu modificaria o banco local para usar SQL Compact. Você passará a usar idioma de SQL compatível com SQL Server, sem as idiossincrasias do Access, e evita os riscos elevados de basear seu aplicativo em um banco MDF. Poderá até compartilhar bastante código entre cliente e servidor (se tiver código no servidor). O SYNC funciona com qualquer banco ADO.NET, mas acredito que bancos compatíveis nas duas pontas sejam a melhor opção para evitar dores de cabeça.

Comment: Obrigado pelas opniões! @Loudenvier